# "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500" IN Volley

Tags: android-volley, laravel-5

I am using laravel framework for writing api. And i have an insert query, that is called product saving.

```
    $returnData     =   array('status'=>false);

    $this->email                    =   $data['email'];
    $this->tran_status              =   true;
    **$this->save();**
```

I needed response after this save function.

I could able to echo the values.But when this goes to save, no response has been displayed on application end.

But using REST APi client my code is working fine.

Please help me